# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un hola mundo en Java que demuestre que sé programación asíncrona?

Tags: java, asincronismo

El hola mundo en Java normal es algo así:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

¿Qué modificaciones le tendría que hacer para que obtenga le mismo resultado, pero usando asincronismo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La manera mas sencilla es creando un thread, en este ejemplo se ejecuta un hello world desde un thread nuevo y otro desde thread principal (el main de la aplicación). Es probable que se ejecute primero el código del thread principal aunque hayamos ejecutado el thread creado antes.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
        String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println("Hello world from Thread "+currentThreadName);
    });
    
    thread.start();
    
    String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("Hello world from Thread "+currentThreadName);
}
```

Este sería un ejemplo con RxJava, el cual usa el patrón de diseño observador. Aquí retransmite un valor, en este caso la cadena Hello World from RxJava a sus subscriptores.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Flowable.just("Hello World from RxJava").subscribe(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("Hello World from Main");
}
```

Y este código es en [rxjava](/questions/tagged/rxjava) como está en la primer respuesta

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Flowable.just("Hello")
                .compose(cadena -> Flowable.just(cadena.blockingFirst() + " World"))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

La forma que se me ocurrió fue con [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) que existe desde [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String args[]){
     CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello")
                .thenCompose(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> s + " World!"))
                .thenAccept(value -> System.out.println(value));
  }
}
```

Como se puede observar, recibe funciones supplier para obtener datos, funciones de dos parámetros para transformación y consumidores.